# how to jquery event bind to function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input id='btnExcelRead' name='btnExcelRead' type='submit' runat='server'/>   <- actually asp:button
<input id='excelUpload' name='excelUpload' type='file' />   
<input id='txtStartDate' type='text' />
<input id='txtEndDate' type='text' />
```

..

```
$(function(){

          $("#btnExcelRead").click(CheckValidation);

        });

        var CheckValidation = function() {
            if ($("#excelUpload").val() === "") {
                alert("Select file");
                return false;
            }
            if ($("$txtStartDate").val() === "") {
                alert("Check the start date!");
                return false;
            }
            if ($("$txtEndDate").val() === "") {
                alert("Check the end date!");
                return false;
            }
        }
```

here i made simple jquery code.

I want to bind function when  btnExcelRead button click.

is this originally wrong way?

Comment: you're missing a ; at the end, and the function definition should be inside the on ready bit. What's your question?

Comment: sorry about my poor english.. I want to execute `CheckValidation` function when `btnExcelRead` button click.

Comment: avobe this code, i make a wrong selector. it should be changed( $txtStartDate -> #txtStartDate , $txtEndDate -> #txtEndDate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is valid, aside from the selectors, I would reformat is a bit, like this:

```
$(function(){
      $("#btnExcelRead").click(CheckValidation);
});

function CheckValidation () {
    if ($("#excelUpload").val() === "") {
        alert("Select file");
        return false;
    }
    if ($("#txtStartDate").val() === "") {
        alert("Check the start date!");
        return false;
    }
    if ($("#txtEndDate").val() === "") {
        alert("Check the end date!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

[You can see a demo of it working here](http://jsfiddle.net/SshdM/)

You have `$txtStartDate` and `$txtEndDate` for your selectors, I think you meant `#txtStartDate` and `#txtEndDate` here (I assume you're finding them by ID).  Also if you want a named function, just make one :) If you store a variable pointing to a anonymous function, make sure to put a `;` after it, since that's a statement.

Comment: also, returning false makes no sense here

Comment: @colinmarc: Sure it does, what if that's a submit button for the form?

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#btnExcelRead").click(function(){CheckValidation()});
```

Comment: Yuck! WHY add an extra function that does nothing but call an existing function? It changes the context of `this`, but in this case that's not a consideration.

Comment: This doesn't work correctly. doesn't pass return value of the `CheckValidation`

Answer (score -1):

You have to declare the callback before calling it like follows:

```
    var CheckValidation = function() {
        if ($("#excelUpload").val() === "") {
            alert("Select file");
            return false;
        }
        if ($("$txtStartDate").val() === "") {
            alert("Check the start date!");
            return false;
        }
        if ($("$txtEndDate").val() === "") {
            alert("Check the end date!");
            return false;
        }
    }

    $(function(){

      $("#btnExcelRead").click(CheckValidation);

    });
```

Comment: Nick, your code in that demo is different than what GeekTantra and I both posted in one key respect: you've translated the `var CheckValidation = function()` format into the `function CheckValidation()` format. See this demo for the version as GeekTantra, sunglim, and I all wrote it: http://jsfiddle.net/p357H/

Comment: @VoteyDisciple: That's because jsfiddle is wrapping your code in `docuemnt.ready`, since you've selected `onLoad` on the left, change it to "No wrap", like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4xUMA/ Then the variable gets defined before `document.ready` runs.

Comment: Not my downvotes here, rarely do I ever, but you should keep certain things in mind, mainly the possibility that the problem's completely unrelated to what *looks* like the problem, e.g. selectors.

Comment: @Nick - Wow, you *really* don't down-vote. I mean 6 out of 1,890? Come on man! Live a little!  ;o)